# Read paths in csv and open in unix

Tags: python, unix

I need to read paths in a csv and go to these file paths in unix. I am wondering if there is any way to do that using unix or python commands. I am unsure of how to proceed and I am not able to find much resources in the net either.
The number of rows in the excel.csv is a lot and similar to below. I need to open the excel.csv and then read the first line and go to this file path. Once this file is opened using the file path, I need to be able to read the file and extract out certain information. I tried using python for this but I am unable to find much information and I am wondering if I can use unix commands to solve this. I am clueless on how to proceed for this one so I would appreciate any reference or help using either python or unix commands. Thank you!

- /folder/file1
- /folder/file2
- /folder/file3

Comment: Does the file contain only file names, one per line? If not, please, [edit] your question and copy&paste a few lines of the input file and format this as a code block, e.g. by using the `{}` tool of the editor field.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be very difficult to do this in Python, as reading csv files is part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Your code could look something like this:

```py
with open('data.csv', newline='') as fh:
    # depending if the first row describes the header or not, 
    # you can also use the simple csv.reader here
    for row in csv.DictReader(fh, strict=True):
        # again, if you use the simple csv.reader, you'll have to access
        # the column via index instead
        file_path = row['path']
        with open(file_path, 'r') as fh2:
           data = fh2.read()
           # do something with data
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am wondering how I can once reading the row containing the path, go to the file stated in the file path itself?

Comment: this is what happens in the last three lines in the example above: file_path is the path of the file in the csv, the next two lines open that file and do something with the data. what you actually do here, depends on your use case.